# Как передать с помощью scp очень много файлов на хостинг?

Tags: scp

Я пользуюсь виртуальным хостингом и мне нужно выкачать на хостинг очень много (несколько тысяч) файлов. Скажем, я переношу на другой хостинг большой веб-форум, у которого есть очень много аттачментов, загруженных его пользователями.

Проблема в том, что на стороне хостинга запрещено выполнение тяжеловесных программ (они так борются с вирусами и спамерами, видимо): любой процесс будет убит через примерно 100 секунд. Для php/perl скриптов (типа веб-форума) это не проблема, но `scp`, копирующий много файлов, будет также убит. По той же причине я не могу заархивировать файлы на текущем хосте, перенести архив и разархивировать их на хостинге.

Как обойти эту ситуацию?

Comment: Будет убит или Вы это предполагаете? SCP работает через SSH. Вряд ли хостер будет убивать SSH-демон.

Comment: @kff если бы существовал хостер, который режет ssh, то у него бы клиентов не было )

Comment: @kff окей, не по времени, а по процессорному времени, за которым следит аккаунтинг на уровне ядра ОС. убивается не общесистемный sshd, а его дочерний процесс, инициированный "входящим" scp. мой кейс возник в связи с работой с хостингом sprinthost-точка-ru, можете взять у них бесплатный тест-драйв и проверить лично =)

Comment: [Офигел] Ничего себе! И как такие ещё выживают?

Comment: Сменить хостера не думали? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень просто: вместо `scp` используйте `rsync` с ключами `azP`. То есть вместо

```
scp -r ./local-dir user@remote-host:~/remote-dir
```

делайте

```
rsync -azP ./local-dir user@remote-host:~/remote-dir
```

Так `rsync` будет передавать файлы по тому же шифрованному ssh-каналу, но при обрыве соединения (если оно будет убито принимающей стороной) при повторе этой команды "умный" `rsync` продолжит копирование с того места, где остановился, чего не умеет `scp`.

Что значат предлагаемые флаги:

- `-a` (то же самое, что и `--archive`) в `rsync` - это алиас для набора флагов `-rlptgoD` - то есть рекурсивно передавать директорию и всё, что вложено в неё, сохраняя симлинки, пермишены файлов, таймстампы файлов, овнеры и группы файлов и директорий, а также корректно обрабатывая файлы-устройства и прочую экзотику
- `-z` - сжимать передаваемые файлы на лету (полезно, если данные преимущественно текстовые, если же данные бинарные - можно не использовать)
- `-P` - разрешить докачку файлов, загруженных частично, при повторном запуске команды (как раз главная для решения озвученной в вопросе проблемы фича `rsync`)

После обрыва передачи (broken pipe) запустите ту же самую команду - `rsync` продолжит с того места, где был прерван.

А чтобы не запускать после обрыва команду руками каждый раз, можно запустить её в цикле:

```
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do rsync <params> ; done
```

Цикл будет повторять запуск `rsync` до тех пор, пока он не завершится с нулевым статусом (т.е. без ошибок).

Comment: Правда у многих хостеров rsync в помине нет и ставить не дадут

Comment: зачем rsync на принимающей стороне? в данном сценарии он нужен только на клиенте. "Once  installed, you can use rsync to any machine that you can access via a remote shell" - man rsync.

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю назначения флага `z`, кто на приемной стороне разжимает файлы. если бы там был rsync, он бы конечно это и сделал.

Comment: сжатие на лету поддерживается на уровне ssh, который будет транспортом для rsync в данном примере (то же самое, что и `scp -C`)

Comment: @AntonioK rsync'у конечно же нужно наличие rsync на принимающей стороне, без него он просто не будет работать. Тем не менее, Ваше решение, ИМХО, оптимальное.